# How can we create the Powerset that return Set instead tuple or list

Tags: python, set

I try to create function to return the Power Sets of a giving set. There are many example but all are only return tuple or list that seem not possible to convert to object set.

```
from itertools import chain, combinations    
def powerset(iterable):
    "powerset([1,2,3]) --> () (1,) (2,) (3,) (1,2) (1,3) (2,3) (1,2,3)"
    s = set(iterable)
    return chain.from_iterable(combinations(s, r) for r in range(len(s)+1))    

g = [powerset({1,2,3})]
result = set(*g)
print(result)
```

Is there anyway I can convert the result to be object set? I expect the result {{},{1},{2},{3},{1,2},{1,3},{2,3},{1,2,3} }

Comment: Side-note, just for fun: You can push the work entirely to the C layer, avoiding the generator expression, by getting `repeat` from `itertools` as well, and using `return chain.from_iterable(map(combinations, repeat(s), range(len(s) + 1)))`. Should slightly speed the processing, especially if whatever consumes it is also a built-in implemented in C (no bytecode interpreter overhead per item at all).

Comment: And one more note: `g = [powerset({1,2,3})]` followed by `result = set(*g)` is a very strange way to do this. Even if you need to two-line it, why not `g = powerset({1,2,3})` followed by `result = set(g)`? Wrapping in a `list` only to immediately unpack it, then never use it again, is strange (especially when passing to the `set` constructor, that wouldn't take more than one argument anyway, and passing an iterator, that can't be reused). Personally, I'd just write `result = set(powerset({1,2,3}))` and skip `g` entirely.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just wrap it in `map(frozenset, ...)` to convert all the `tuple`s to `frozenset`s of the same values:

```
def powerset(iterable):
    "powerset([1,2,3]) --> frozenset() frozenset({1}) frozenset({2}) frozenset({3}) frozenset({1, 2}) frozenset({1, 3}) frozenset({2, 3}) frozenset({1, 2, 3})"
    s = sorted(set(iterable))  # Sorted to get predictable ordering from combinations
    return map(frozenset, chain.from_iterable(combinations(s, r) for r in range(len(s)+1)))
```

If you weren't making a `set` of all the results, you could use `map(set, ...)` instead, but `set`s are not legal members of another `set`, while `frozenset` is, so `map(frozenset, ...)` is what you want in this case.

Keep in mind that `set` (and `frozenset`) are ordered arbitrarily, so the results might not be in the order you expect, but it would be equivalent to the output you're interested in.

Answer (score -1):

I think the question seem not exactly possible to implement.
It is impossible to create set of sets, so the question is not make sense.

Comment: A `set` of `frozenset`s is entirely doable though; as long as they don't need to mutate the inner `frozenset`s, it works just fine.

Comment: Understood, but what I want is to implement the pure subset. In side the frozenset seem like also not allow to contains the set of sets, that why I conclude my requirement is not possible.

Comment: This is beginning to sound like [an XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/322040). You can nest to any depth with `frozenset`s of `frozenset`s of `frozenset`s, ad infinitum, and `frozenset` is (aside from the mutating methods) 100% compatible with `set` (even more so than `tuple` is with `list`) so while the display format is different, you can do almost anything you want with arbitrarily nested `frozenset`s (and the outermost one can be a `set`). Why would an arbitrarily nest depth of `frozenset`s not serve your purpose? That would help find the X in your XY problem.

Comment: @ShadowRanger   I do following your advise, but seem not work for me
I did  tested like below:
`s = [ a for a in powerset({1,2,3}) ]`
then cast to set 
`s=set(s)`
Then try to check  `s.issuperset({2})` . The result is false, so I think it not correct by somehow.

Then, I try to just test to create a set of set, `s = set{ {1},{2,3} }` that seem also not possible. That why it seem I do misunderstand the primary concept.

Comment: You're misusing `issuperset`, and you need to use `frozenset` any time you insert or test for membership in a set. So instead of `s.issuperset({2})` for instance, you'd do `s.issuperset({frozenset({2})})` (because `s` contains `frozenset({2})`, and your code was effectively asking if `s` contained `2` itself, unwrapped), or for single elements like this, you'd just test `frozenset({2}) in s` (asking if that specific frozenset is in `s`) which is simpler and more efficient.

Comment: Similarly, `s = set{{1}, {2, 3}}` is wrong on multiple levels. 1) You need either the braces or the `set` constructor with parentheses, not `set` + `{}` with no curly braces, so you'd omit the `set`, making it `s = {{1}, {2, 3}}`. But that's not enough, because 2) `set` literals are always `set`, not `frozenset`, so you need to call the `frozenset` constructor to convert to immutable `frozenset`s, e.g. `s = {frozenset({1}), frozenset({2, 3})}`, or if you have a lot of them and don't want to type `frozenset` over and over, `s = set(map(frozenset, [{1}, {2, 3}, ...more...]))` to shorten it.

Comment: Also, you seem to have a misunderstanding as to Python iterables in general. `[a for a in powerset({1,2,3})]` is a slow way to spell `list(powerset({1,2,3}))` (a no-op comprehension is pointless; the `list` constructor happily consumes arbitrary iterables to make a new `list`). And even that's not necessary; you seem to think the `set()` constructor only takes a `list` as input, but like `list()`, it accepts *any* iterable, so `s = set(powerset({1,2,3}))` would work just fine with no need for a temporary `list`, as long as the `powerset` iterator is producing `tuple`s or `frozenset`s.

Comment: Thanks, actually my code use the set constructor(``s = [ a for a in P2({1,2,3})]
f = set(s)``), otherwise it raised error. 

What I exactly need is the superset for a giving set, that it. I would not use the frozenset since  it not inline with the other code.  But thank you the advise.

Comment: Look, I can't say what you're doing (you're being too cagey on other details), but I can tell you, with *100%* certainty, that if `s = [ a for a in P2({1,2,3})] f = set(s)` works, and `s` is not otherwise used, `f = set(P2({1,2,3}))` will also work, and more efficiently (creating the `set` directly, without needing to build and later discard, a temporary `list`). (Technically, there is an edge case if `s` and/or `f` are global variables and `P2` uses them live as it computes its results, but that isn't the case here, and it would be *seriously* pathological to do it that way).